# How the tableview works - IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a table view in which each cell I have added a object. Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath I want to do some GUI action based on object included. For ex.

```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

    // Got object.
    modal_info *obj = [self.listData objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    if (obj->status != OFI_VC_USER_STATE_HEADING)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = obj->combined_name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = obj->email;

        // Set Image
        UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"silhouette_user.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    }
    return cell;
```

But in tabular view name and image is showing for header row even though I am setting nil. Am I doing anything wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you want to add the image into section header

Comment: You should not be directly accessing iVars with the struct access operator (`->`).  Use properties instead.

Comment: @neon samuel I have fixed it. Its my mistake I have not set value properly while adding. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Check the if condition i.e value of **obj->status** is correct for each cell. It seems like the control is not entering the else block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@neon samuel I have fixed it. Its my mistake I have not set value properly while adding. Thanks anyway. :) – Feroz Mohideen